# Странная форма написание стилей

Tags: css

Я однажды видел в CSS, что писали стили примерно так:

```
.test {
   .test ul {
      .test li {
         // styles ... 
      }
   }
   .test a {
      // styles ... 
   }
}
```

Какая форма будет правильной?

Comment: Я думаю, это не простой `css`, это https://mrmlnc.gitbooks.io/less-guidebook-for-beginners/content/chapter_1/css-reprocessors.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Такое описание стилей соответствует тому, как они описываются в CSS-препроцессорах, таких, как LESS, SCSS, Sass и т.п.

**CSS препроцессор** (от англ. CSS preprocessor) — это надстройка над CSS, которая добавляет ранее недоступные возможности для CSS, с помощью новых синтаксических конструкций.

Например, код, написанный на LESS:

```
.test {
    width:100%;
    ul {
       list-style:none;
       li {
         padding:0;
         margin:0;
      }
   }
   a {
      display:inline-block;
   }
}
```

будет скомпилирован в привычный нам CSS следующим образом:

```
.test {
  width:100%;
}

.test ul {
  list-style:none;
}

.test ul li {
  padding:0;
  margin:0;
}

.test a {
  display:inline-block;
}
```

Подробнее о препроцессорах можно почитать [тут](https://webref.ru/layout/advanced-html-css/preprocessors).

Answer (score 2):

Это SASS-SCSS. Модуль, включенный в Haml. Sass — это метаязык на основе CSS, предназначенный для увеличения уровня абстракции CSS кода и упрощения файлов каскадных таблиц стилей.
<sub>[Описание из wikipedia](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sass)</sub>

Или же LESS. LESS — это динамический язык стилей, который разработал Alexis Sellier. Он создан под влиянием языка стилей Sass, и, в свою очередь, оказал влияние на его новый синтаксис «SCSS», в котором также использован синтаксис, являющийся расширением СSS.
<sub>[Описание из wikipedia](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/LESS_(%D1%8F%D0%B7%D1%8B%D0%BA_%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B9))</sub>

Точно не назову, т.к. у них подобный синтаксис

Comment: А разве это не less?

Comment: @Cheg, тоже схожу. Но мне попало на ум SASS, так как тут стиль только в последнем элементе.

Comment: @Cheg, сейчас уточню

Comment: Такая запись может быть и в stylus например) В любом случае речь идет по препроцессоре

Comment: @Cheg, уточнил.

Answer (score 0):

Можно написать вот так

```
.test ul li {

}

.test a {

}
```

Еще можно так:

```
.test > ul > li {

}

.test > a {

}
```

Comment: Это разные вещи. Первый вариант применяется к элементам на любом уровне вложенности, второй - только на первом.